# this keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

Please explain what is `this.value` in the below code.

What value will be passed in the second parameter of `calcLapseDays` function.?

I guess current text box value but current textbox value is blank then what will be the value.

Please guide.

sample:

```
<html:text property="flEndDt" readonly="true" tabindex="<%=(i2++).toString() %>" 
 onfocus="calcLapseDays(document.forms[0].reqRcvdDate.value,this.value)"`/>
```

Comment: for a blank textbox the value will be "" (the empty string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the function is called on an inline event handler, `this` will point to the DOM element from which the event originated.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the element you're working with/typing in.

Answer (score 0):

To say an example for you, the `this` keyword refers to the current element. Consider this input:

```
<input type="text" onclick="alert(this.value);" />
```

Now, type something in this and click on the textbox to alert the value inside it!